# Android app searching array

Tags: android, xml, arrays, search

I want to start programming Android again.
Because I didn't know alot about this, I have to learn the basics again.
What I want to create is the following.

I want to create a xml document "words.xml"

```
<dictionary>
<word>
    <id>1</id>
    <word>hallo</word>
    <translation>hello</translation>
</word>
…
<word>
    <id>231</id>
    <word>familie</word>
    <translation>family</translation>
</word></dictionary>
```

Then I want to create an interface with a textinput.
So if I enter for example "231", the code has to search in the xml file for id '231' and say Hallo = Hello, something like that.

Can you give me some tips how I can start with this?

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be a custom xml parser which creates a map variable storing ID=>(word,translation); although of course that wouldn't be feasible for a large dictionary. Android can use an SQLite database though which might be useful. A quick search pointed to [this SQLite tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). Apart from that somebody else will need to comment.